# Python Requests - detecting session timeouts

Tags: python, session, cookies

In the amazing [Python Requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), does it have the capability to automatically detect timeouts or cookie expiries? I'm logging into a page to retrieve some Json, and don't want to waste bandwidth by logging in each time:

```
s=requests.Session()
login_url='https://site/login'
payload = {'password': 'pw', 'email': 'email'}
loginr=s.post(login_url, data=payload)
url='https://site/json.json'
json_string = s.get(url)
the_data = json_string.json()
```

Or will I have to detect if s exists, then get the cookie dict, then check if the specific "logged in" cookie exists?

Thanks

Will

Comment: Most session cookie implementations time out on the *server side*. Your only option is to detect if you are redirected back to the login page.

Comment: I see. Annoyingly there's no redirection in place, so I'll have to check for a specific list inside the json, *then* login if it's not there. Thanks for the reply Martijn